# Intrusion DetecTion DataSet

Tags: system, detection, tcpdump, arff

First Off all i hope my subject will not delte because maybe out Topic But i Didn't Find better Website to Post on it.
I'm working on Intrusion detection Project, as my research Most of intrusion detection dataset (KDD,DARPA, CDX,ISCX...) every base had their proper format(arff,tcmpdump,dump,csv...) So i want to Convert DataSet from Dump and Tcpdump to Arff, to arff format (if you have better idea to make the dataset into same format i'll be thankfull), what is the best way to do this ?
And the last question is the best Intrusion detection System, which can analyse Heterogenous Dataset format and give me Detection Rate of every Attack

Answer (score 1):

First, the dataset KDDCup is based on traffic collected of DARPA. The Darpa Dataset isn’t labeled and contains only traffic collected of experiments, that is why format Tcpdump.

So, KDDCup is work on DARPA. They analyse all traffic(packets) and selected features that help algorithms classified traffic as normal and anomaly. We call this approach "Offline Learning" when we have the labeled data.